Remove chapter numbering from table of content with tocloft
I have formatted a ToC with tocloft package. I have it almost right, but I would like to remove the numbers of the chapters; just leave the chapter names. Anyone have any ideas? The job is to remove the "1" in front of chapter 1 and keep the same indent as the List of figures. Get rid of "1" and move "CHAPTER 1" to the left to be aligned with the List of figures.


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the LaTeX code (including the document class that's in use) that gives rise to the screenshot you posted.

You want to locally make \numberline a no-op when typesetting a chapter in the table of contents.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\l@chapter}{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\l@chapter}{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\end{document}


